# Unable to store facebook profile picture to database in mvc 4

Tags: facebook, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am creating a project where the user can login using Facebook. I want to retrieve the users details based on Facebook login. I am getting details like Facebook Id, First Name, Last Name, Gender, Locale and Facebook Link and store it in database. I am not able to get email id, ip address and profile pic of the user. For the profile pic I gave varbinary(max) as the data type but when I try to save it to the database I get the error -

> Error reading bytes. Unexpected token: StartObject. Line 1, position
>   191.

My coding is as follows:

**FacebookUserModel.cs:**

```
public partial class FacebookUserModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string locale { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public byte[] picture { get; set; }
}
```

**AccountController.cs:**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private DetailsFBEntities1 db = new DetailsFBEntities1();
    //
    // GET: /Account/Login

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult FacebookLogin(FacebookLoginModel model)
    {
        Session["uid"] = model.uid;
        Session["accessToken"] = model.accessToken;
        Session["ip"] = Request.UserHostAddress;
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UserDetails(FacebookUserModel umodel)
    {
        try
        {
            string ip = Request.UserHostAddress;
            var client = new FacebookClient(Session["accessToken"].ToString());
            //byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("umodel.picture");
            dynamic fbresult = client.Get("me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,gender,locale,link,picture");

            FacebookUserModel facebookUser = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookUserModel>(fbresult.ToString());
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.FacebookUserModels.Add(facebookUser);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return View(facebookUser);
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

**Facebook.js:**

```
function InitialiseFacebook(appId) {

    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: appId,
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
            var credentials = { uid: response.authResponse.userID, accessToken: response.authResponse.accessToken };
            SubmitLogin(credentials);
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                alert("user is logged into fb");
            }
            else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') { alert("user is not authorised"); }
            else { alert("user is not conntected to facebook"); }

        });

        function SubmitLogin(credentials) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/account/facebooklogin",
                type: "POST",
                data: credentials,
                error: function () {
                    alert("error logging in to your facebook account.");
                },
                success: function () {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });
        }

    };

    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement('script');
        js.id = id;
        js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

}
```

**UserDetails.cs:**

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Picture</td><td><img src='@Model.picture' /></td></tr>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)
    <tr><td>Facebook Id</td><td>@Model.id</td></tr>
    <tr><td>First Name</td><td>@Model.first_name</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Last Name</td><td>@Model.last_name</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Gender</td><td>@Model.gender</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Locale</td><td>@Model.locale</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Facebook Link</td><td>@Model.link</td></tr>
</table>
```

I am new at this so please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took picture as varchar(max) instead of varbinary(max) and assigned values as follows:

```
FacebookUserModel facebookUser = new FacebookUserModel
{
    first_name = fbresult.first_name,
    gender = fbresult.gender,
    id = fbresult.id,
    last_name = fbresult.last_name,
    locale = fbresult.locale,
    link = fbresult.link,
    picture = fbresult.picture.data.url,
};
```

So inside picture we only get the url of that picture and we can use it wherever we want it.